# What is the interplanar distance? Bragg´s law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

An X-ray (wavelength λ= 12.4 pm falls on a crystal)
The incidence angle (Θ) is the same as the dispersion angle = 16.6 degrees.
What is the interplanar distance if we observe the first order maximum? 
I'm sure I should use the Bragg formula.
2*distance*sin(Θ )=N*λ
However when I get the distance I get a negative number, and isn't that impossible?

Comment: How does $d = \lambda/(2\sin(16.6°))$ give you a negative number?

Comment: so according to you the answer is 12.4/(2sin(16.6°))=22.96pm?

Answer (score 2):

Your'e correct that Bragg's law gives the inter-planar distance as

$d={\frac {n\lambda}{2\sin \left( \theta \right) }}$

Since the order n is positive, and the wavelength λ is positive, the only other variable that could produce a negative
sign is the *sin*(θ) term.

Ensure that you are actually using 16.6°, and not 16.6 radians. Calculating 
*sin*(16.6 rad) does yield a negative number. This may be a source of error.